# Folland's Real Analysis 7.11

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Suppose $\mu$ is a Radon measure on $X$ such that $\mu(\left\lbrace x \right\rbrace)=0$ for all $x \in X$, and $A \in \mathbb{B}_X$ satisfies $0 < \mu(A) < \infty$. Then for any $\alpha$ such that $0 < \alpha < \mu(A)$ there is a Borel set $B \subset A$ such that $\mu(B) = \alpha$

I'm not even sure how to start this problem. It seems like a nice result, but any hints on how to start?

Comment: I had a similar problem in a class of mine, this Wikipedia article was somewhat helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28measure_theory%29#Non-atomic_measures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the broad outline: fix $\alpha$ with $0<\alpha<\mu(A)$, and define
$$ S_{\alpha}=\{B\subset A:B=U\cap A,\;U\; \mathrm{open},\;\mu(B)\leq \alpha\} $$

$S_{\alpha}$ is non-empty, and if $S_{\alpha}$ is partially ordered by inclusion, then one can show that it satisfies the hypotheses of Zorn's lemma. Therefore $S_{\alpha}$ has a maximal element $B$, which can be shown to satisfy $\mu(B)=\alpha$.

Comment: Can you explain what "partially ordered by inclusion" means?

Comment: If $B$ and $C$ are two elements of $S_{\alpha}$, define $B\prec C$ if $B\subset C$.

Comment: Ok cool thank you! I'll give it a shot andd see how the problem goes

Comment: How do we know that $S_{\alpha}$ is not empty ?

Comment: Choose some $x\in A$, then since $\mu(\{x\})=0$ there exists (by outer regularity) an open set $U$ with $x\in U$ and $\mu(U)<\alpha$. Let $B=A\cap U$, then $B\in S_{\alpha}$.

Comment: I wonder if Zorn's lemma is a necessary condition for this result to hold...