# Radon measure on locally compact Hausdorff spaces

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $\mu$ is a Radon measure on a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ such that $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for all $x\in X$ and $A \in B_X$ satisfies $0<\mu(A)<\infty$. Then for any $\alpha$ such that $0<\alpha<\mu(A)$, there is a Borel set $B\subset A$ such that $\mu(B)=\alpha$.

I am reviewing measure theory for my exam and got stuck on this question. Can any one help me ? Thank you very much.

Comment: See this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1735558/follands-real-analysis-7-11/1735568#1735568