# Does $\mu(\{x\})=0$ imply non-atomic for Radon measure?

Tags: measure-theory

I am wondering if the following statement is true.

Let $\mu$ be a Radon measure satisfying $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for all $x\in X$, then $\mu$ is non-atomic. (Non-atomic means that for all $B\in \mathcal{B}_X$, if $\mu(B)>0$, there exists $A\subseteq B$ in $\mathcal{B}_X$ s.t. $0<\mu(A)<\mu(B)$).

This question arise when I am trying to do problem 7.11 on Folland real analysis.

> If $\mu$ is a Radon measure on $X$ s.t. $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for all $x\in X$, and $A\in \mathcal{B}_X$ satisfies $0<\mu(A)<\infty$. Then for any $\alpha$ such that $0<\alpha< \mu(A)$ there is a Borel set $B\subseteq A$ s.t. $\mu(B)=\alpha$.

There is a theorem says that all non-atomic finite measure satisfies this intermediate-value theorem. So basically I need show is $\mu$ restricted on $A$ is non-atomic. However, I $\mu$ is not assumed to be $\sigma$-finite. So $\mu$ restricted on $A$ is not necessarily a Radon measure. But I guess the proof idea might be similar.

There is post about problem 7.11. [Folland's Real Analysis 7.11](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1735558/634219). However, I am just not quite convinced by the answer. First of all the proof of intermediate value theorem (of non-atomic finite measure) does not require Zorn's Lemma. Also, is it possible to have for all $x\in A$, there exists $U$ open containing $x$ such that $\mu(U\cap A)=0$? The definition of Radon measure does not assume positivity of measure on open sets. With this I feel like the proof in the link might break.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\mu$ restricted to $A$ is finite

Comment: @Masacroso I have some ideas about this, and I have posted an answer below

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the linked answer? Also, it looks like that answer doesn't required $\mu(A)<\infty$ nor does it seem to require $\mu(\{x\}) = 0\forall x$, just one $x\in A$ having $0$ measure is fine.

Comment: @stackex33 You mean the answer posted below? Indeed I used them. $\mu(A)<\infty$ is used when chosen $U\supseteq A$, and $\mu(x)=0$ is used when choosing $\mu(U_x)<\epsilon$. I am not sure about the linked answer. Even we prove the there is a maximal set in the chain, how can we know this maximal equals to $\alpha$. I guess he tries to say if it is less, we can add one more point neighbourhood to make it a bit larger, but what about if all such neighbourhood has measure 0?

Comment: No, the linked answer. But yes, in the answer below we need $\mu(A)<\infty$, but I don't understand how you get $F$.

Comment: (I thought it was right, but now) I'm not completely sure how the maximal element would have measure $\alpha$, but perhaps assuming a maximal element $B$ has $\mu(B)<\alpha$, one could take an open $U\supseteq B$ such that $\mu(U)<\mu(B)+\epsilon<\alpha$ and consider $U\cap A$. The problem is that we may have $U\cap A = B$. And adding neighbourhoods of points has the problem you mention, namely them having measure $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some ideas.. The following is a sketch.

WLOG, we can prove there exists $B\subseteq A$ s.t. $0<\mu(B)<\mu(A)$.
Let $U\supseteq A$ be an open set satisfying $\mu(U)$ is arbitrarily closed to $\mu(A)$. Apply outer regularity of $\mu$ to $U\backslash A$, we can find closed $F\subseteq A$ relative to $U$ s.t. $\mu(F)$ is arbitrarily closed to $\mu(A)$. Let's assume $\mu(F)=\mu(A)$. By inner regularity of $\mu$, take a compact $K\subseteq U$ which has measure arbitrarily closed to $\mu(U)$. By doing this, we can make $K\cap F$ has positive measure by exclusion-inclusion formula. Take $K\cap F$

Assume $\mu(K\cap F)=\mu(A)$. $K\cap F$ is compact, for every $x\in K\cap F$, there exists open $U$ s.t. $\mu(U)<\epsilon$. Then $U_{x}$ form a cover of $K\cap F$. It admits finite subcover. Clearly, it's impossible to have all $\mu(U\cap K\cap F)=0$. Let $V$ be one open set s.t. $\mu(V\cap K\cap F)>0$.  So take $(K\cap F)\backslash V$ will produce the desired $B$.

Comment: I don't understand what $F$ is. How do we arrive at $F$ from outer regularity?

Comment: @stackex33 take open $V\supseteq U\backslash A$ which has arbitrarily closed.measure, then take $F=U\backslash V$

Comment: Ok, but this $F$ is need not be closed in $X$, but everything else looks fine (within some $\epsilon$ : ). $K\cap F$ will be closed in $K$ because $F$ is closed in $U$ (not necessarily in $X$). Yes, we will also require $\mu(\{x\}) = 0$ for every $x$ to obtain $U_x$.

Comment: @stackex33  Good point. It is fixed.

Answer (score 5):

**Theorem**. Let  $\mu $ be a regular Borel measure on a topological space $X$.  If $\mu (\{x\})=0$, for every $x$ in $X$, then $\mu $ has no atoms.

*Proof*.  Suppose by contradiction that $A$ is an atom for $\mu $.  By regularity
$$
  \sup\{\mu (K): K\subseteq A, \ K \text{ is compact}\} = \mu (A)>0,
  $$
so there is at least one compact $K\subseteq A$ with nonzero measure.   Fixing such a $K$, observe that it is also an atom.

For each $x$ in $K$, again using regularity, we have
$$
  \inf\{\mu (U): \{x\}\subseteq U, \  U \text{ is open}\}  = \mu (\{x\}) = 0,
  $$
so we may choose an open set $U_x$, containing $x$, such that $\mu (U_x)< \mu (K)$.

We then obtain a cover $\{U_x\}_{x\in K}$ for $K$, which therefore admits a finite subcover, say  $\{U_{x_i}\}_{1\leq i\leq n}$.

Setting $V_i=U_{x_i}\cap K$,
observe  that $V_i\subseteq K$, and that $\mu (V_i)< \mu (K)$, so we deduce that $\mu (V_i)=0$, due to the fact that $K$ is an atom.

Moreover $K\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^nV_i$, so by subaditivity we get
$$
  \mu (K)\leq \sum_{i=1}^n\mu (V_i)=0,
  $$
a contradiction.